# Change translation in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, translation, context-menu

I would like ask you, where can I rewrite one translation in context menu of Nautilus, because in my language it is not correct translated.

Thank you

Comment: Try nautilus source > po > appropriate  file  > edit > rebuild

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change the translation easily. You'll need to [report a bug against the Ubuntu Translations project](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-translations/+filebug) ([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Filing_a_translation_bug)) ([source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/Issues)). You can also hunt around the [Ubuntu Translations wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations) to find out more about translating.

Comment: Thank you, i reported bug, but i dont want to wait for X months if someone will release new version. Is possible to download Nautilus language pack, and decrypt it, change it, and encrypt?

Comment: I don't know, sounds pretty technical, hopefully someone with some more know-how than me can help.